# Bash - Remove odd/even lines based on text match on specific line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text input with field and value pairs, say:

```
a=1
b=2
a=6
a=5
b=7
```

I want output:

```
a=1
b=2
a=5
b=7
```

basically remove the odd lines if it doesn't contain 'a', even lines if it doesn't contain 'b'.

In this case remove [a=6] for the output, and preserve the complete a=* \n b=* pairs.

I feel like this is possible with awk, but couldn't find anything that address this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well try and post some code... in awk, you can use `NR` to get current line number... from that you can determine whether it is odd/even numbered line... then apply your filtering..

Comment: also check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for learning resources and more

Comment: The last line `b=7` should not be output: it is an odd line and it doesn't contain 'a', So it has to be removed. If this is correct, see my solution below:

Comment: Only [a=6 should be removed], and then [a=5] becomes a odd line, and [b=7] becomes a even line. But I see the ambiguity.

Comment: Why remove `a=6` in favor of `a=5`? `a=6` is already an odd numbered line.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't explain myself well. Let me try again. 

Imagine 'a' is user, and 'b' is address. I want to remove any data where the user only inputted his name but not an address. 

I only want to keep the completed name/address pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: see the clarification of the OP above: when an even line is deleted, the next line becomes even, and the same with odd lines.

**Second Edit**: according to a further explanation of the OP (he said: "Sorry. I didn't explain myself well. Let me try again. Imagine 'a' is user, and 'b' is address. I want to remove any data where the user only inputted his name but not an address. I only want to keep the completed name/address pairs"), the solution is next command:

```
awk -F= '$1=="a"{a=$0} (a!="")&&($1=="b"){print a; print; a=""}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
a=1
b=2
a=5
b=7
```

Comment: Wait. The OP says: "Imagine 'a' is user, and 'b' is address. I want to remove any data where the user only inputted his name but not an address. I only want to keep the completed name/address pairs." In that case, the script above is not correct. 3d line should be `a=5` and not `a=6`.

Comment: Thanks - this works. I am seeking explanation on the second edit.
What logic does command {print a; print; a=""} do? 
What variable does the [a] in (a!="") and {a=$0} represent?

Comment: The variable `a` contains the previous line beginning with "a=" and that is not yet output. So `print a; print` prints the previous line (in the variable `a`) and the current line, and resets `a` to an empty string.

Comment: I think next title will explain better your problem: "Print 2 subsequent lines lines according to a specific pattern". In my humble opinion, you were starring at one possible implementation depending on odd/even lines, and that was limiting your scope to find an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/a.*\n.*b/!D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space. If the pattern space does not contain an `a` followed by a `b` delete the first line and repeat, otherwise print both lines and repeat.